# Metrics for Eclipse Indigo C++

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse-plugin, metrics

Are there any plugins for Eclipse Indigo that will give source code metrics for C++?

I am working on a system that is not connected to the internet so I need to set up my own archive. I have tried downloading and installing metrics2 but the archive cannot be read.

Answer (score 0):

i use a source metrics application (ProjectCodeMeter) that can integrate into eclipse as a tool:
http://www.projectcodemeter.com/cost_estimation/help/FN_commandline.htm